Update values in df from other df sharing same column names
Let's say I have two separate data frames. I want to keep the df_old, but I want to replace the values (with shared column names) with the values from the df_new. How would I do that?
So "other" in df_old would maintain values but values from other column names would update with the df_new values. Also worth stating that these two data frames could contain one hundred or more column names.
avg_sleep <- c(21, 18, 17, 10)
rating <- 1:4
other <- 5:8
df_old = data.frame(rating, avg_sleep, other)

avg_sleep <- c(16,15,18,19)
rating <- 2:5
df_new = data.frame(rating, avg_sleep)



You can overwrite the columns, using the new column names a reference:
df_old[names(df_new)] <- df_new


  rating avg_sleep other
1      2        16     5
2      3        15     6
3      4        18     7
4      5        19     8



Awesome, thanks so much! If some of the columns aren't identical, is there a package that would match those including similar strings, or would you need to move into token matching? I.e. would it be easier to manually change those names so that they would match (given that those column names would not be changing in the future).

Have a look at e.g. stringdist::stringdist().

Try modifyList
modifyList(df_old, df_new)
##   rating avg_sleep other
## 1      2        16     5
## 2      3        15     6
## 3      4        18     7
## 4      5        19     8

